# How can I repair these icons

Tags: gnome, 20.04, icons, gtk3, icon-themes

[image]

Look at the top bar, the icons are missing, can someone help me on how to repair this

Comment: Does ```gtk-update-icon-cache``` help?

Comment: I see icons in the top bar. Please explain. Have you chosen another icon theme or GNOME theme in `Tweaks`? Reset to the defaults and see if your problem is resolved.

Comment: gtk-update-icon-cache didn't help

Comment: is that red icon, he's on place of many missing icons

Comment: reset to default didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Your icon theme does not "serve" the icons needed for the panel. So if you selected an older theme, it might have not all icons needed or named.

What you can do:
Select a theme that more or less suits you and which has been updated not too long ago.
You could compare the working theme with yours, copy the missing icons or rename the appropriate icons according to the working theme.
You could even make a "new" theme out if and publish it in "gnome-look.org"